# My stylesheet doesn't seem to apply anything to my html, any idea why this could be?

Tags: html, css

Have gone through some basic tutorials for HTML/CSS and am trying to play around with styling elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="background-color: purple">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>insert title here</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="first/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Main Header</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to style h1 but that has been unsuccessful and this is the only thing on my stylesheet

```
h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

I was unable to do the same action when trying to style html so I went with inline but I don't want to have to do this with everything I'm attempting to style. Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening? Could I be linking it incorrectly to the stylesheet?

Comment: Can you show us the architecture of the files ? Your css file is in a first folder ? And the type in the link tag is not mandatory I think

Comment: So I have the html and css files both in the first folder, could this be the issue? I removed that just now actually and it didn't affect anything.

Comment: if the css file is in the same folder as your html file, you should edit the ```href``` from ```href="first/style.css"``` to```href="style.css"```

Comment: That fixed the issue, really appreciate you taking the time to reply. I'll have to keep this in mind in the future

Comment: i made an answer, can you accept it ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style is fine, something small config like file structure would be off, if you are starting off, put them in one file first like this and then decouple them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>insert title here</title>
  
  <style>
h1{
color:blue
} 
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Main Header</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

starting small always saves a lot of time

Comment: That definitely worked and I appreciate the response but I'm trying to slowly build on this and plan on moving to an external stylesheet in the future. Do you have any tips for decoupling properly or see where any issues could have been?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp This would help

Comment: Much appreciated friend, thanks for taking the time to reply and help a newcomer out

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said, your html file and your css file are in the same folder, so you can remove the `first/` in the `href`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="first/style.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```